# Case-sensitive Okta URLs do not work with snowsql and Python connector. Any workaround?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

If you're trying to connect to Snowflake with `snowsql` or Python connector (apparently used internally by `snowsql`) using Okta SSO and your Okta URL includes case-sensitive parts--you're in bad luck:

```
snowsql -o log_level=DEBUG -a <youraccount> -u <youruser> --authenticator https://someaccount.okta.com/some-CaSe-SenSitiVe-Part
```

The problem is that in Python connector's `connection.py`, line 765 (https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/blob/51d8dba6a3dcf5c60e087f023e5186e8b7175135/connection.py#L765) it uppercases the authenticator parameter, which breaks your case-sensitive Okta URL.

I added an issue in GitHub (https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/257), but meanwhile: anyone knows any workaround?

Comment: It looks like the case-sensitivity of the Okta URL is actually reported as an issue here: https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-js/issues/255.  Just a note.

Comment: No, that's a different issue.

Comment: I actually submitted a pull request yesterday with a fix for the issue #257.